# issue importing bigquery to rstudio

Tags: r, google-bigquery, rstudio

I'm using the following code

```
library(bigrquery)
project <- "api-console-project-176317"
sql <- "SELECT * FROM [api-console-project-176317:DataSources.ATG] where order_date between '2018-01-01' and '2018-12-31'"
ATG <- query_exec(sql, project = project, useLegacySql = FALSE)
```

which does create a Data named ATG with the variable from the table in bigquery, but 0 obj (the Data set is empty)

how can I extract the objects (values) also?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not getting any values since you are using the `LegacySQL` query dialect in your SQL query but setting the `useLegacySql` flag to `FALSE`, which is making fail your statement execution.

I recommend you to use the `` (`) `` instead of the `([)` symbol in case you want to use Standard dialect or set the `useLegacySql` flag to `TRUE` if you want to keep using Legacy. Take a look on [this link](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/google-cloud-platform-for-data-scientists-using-r-with-google-bigquery) where you can find a useful example to use R with BigQuery.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I do need to use legacy SQL, but I'm still not getting any values, only variables.

Comment: In this case, you can verify if you are being [authenticated](https://db.rstudio.com/databases/big-query/#authentication) correctly, as well as review the [BigQuery job and query history](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/bigquery-web-ui#viewing_job_and_query_history), in order to confirm that the statements are being executed as expected; In this way, you will be able to validate them directly in BigQuery and discard connection issues. Additionally, you can review the [Using DBI and dplyr](https://db.rstudio.com/databases/big-query/#using-dbi-and-dplyr) option as a possible workaround.

Answer (score 0):

I've changed to code to be in legacysql but still don't receive the values, only variables

```
library(bigrquery)
project <- "api-console-project-176317"
sql <- "SELECT * FROM [api-console-project-176317:DataSources.ATG] where order_year = 2018"
ATG <- query_exec(sql, project = project, useLegacySql = TRUE)
```